# How do I compute the density of R?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A uniform random number X divides [0, 1] into two segments. Let R be the ratio of the
smaller versus the larger segment. How do I compute the density of R?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this look correct to you?

let $V$ denote the length of the largest piece, and $F_V$ its law. For $t \in [0,1]$,

\begin{align}
P(R \leq t) &= \int_{s=1/2}^1 P\left(R \leq t | V=s \right) F_V(ds)\\
&=\int_{s=1/2}^1  P\left(\frac{1-s}{s} \leq t | V=s \right) F_V(ds)\\
&= \int_{s=1/2}^1 P\left(s \geq \frac{1}{1+t} | V=s \right) F_V(ds)\\
&=\int_{s=1/(1+t)}^1 F_V(ds)\\
&= P\left( V \geq \frac{1}{1+t}\right).
\end{align}

Let $U$ denote a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$. For $s \in [1/2,1]$

$$P(V \geq s) = P(U \leq 1-t) + P(U \geq t) = 2(1-t). $$

So

$$P(R \leq t) = 2\left( 1-\frac{1}{1+t} \right) = \frac{2t}{1+t}.$$

Then density is obtained by differentiating with respect to $t$.

Comment: The answer is 2/ (r+1)^2. I can find a solution here. But, I could not understand it clearly. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/mat135a.pdf

Comment: Ok, well if you differentiate my answer, you indeed get $2/(t+1)^2$. So the question becomes: which part of my solution don't you understand?

Comment: How did you arrive at R = 1-s /s? And, how did it become 1/ 1+t in next step. I am new to this concept.

Comment: I could not understand how you arrived at the first equation...Why are we taking the largest piece alone?

Comment: In the first equality, I condition on the size of the largest piece. In the second equality, we 'know' that the largest piece is of size $s$. Given this information, we 'know' that the smallest piece has size $1-s$. So we 'know' that the ratio is $(1-s)/s$.

Comment: Ok. Got this point. Now, how it become 1/ 1+t?

Comment: I simply rearrange the inequality.

Comment: Ok. Got it. How the limits changed in next step? Please tolerate me. I could not get it clearly...

Comment: Well the event $s \geq 1/(1+t)$ is completely deterministic. It's 'probability' is $1$ if $s$ is bigger than $1/(1+t)$ and zero otherwise. That translates into integrating over the range $1/(1+t)$ up to $1$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The length $S$ of the shorter segment is equidistributed in $\bigl[0,{1\over2}\bigr]$ with constant density $2$. Given $S$ the ratio $R$ you are interested in is the quantity ${S\over 1-S}$. Inversely: Given the ratio $R$ this value is produced by $S={R\over 1+R}$.

We now have to determine cumulative distribution function $F_R$ of the random variable $R$. When $y<0$ then $F_R(y)=0$. When $0\leq y\leq 1$ one has
$$F_R(y)=P[0\leq R\leq y]=P\left[0\leq S\leq{y\over 1+y}\right]={2y\over 1+y}\ ,$$
and when $y>1$ then $F_R(y)=1$. It follows that the pdf $f_R$ of $R$ is given by
$$f_R(y)={d\over dy}F_R(y)={2\over (1+y)^2}\qquad(0\leq y\leq 1)$$
 and $f_R(y)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: NIce! :) But I think here constant density=0.5, if I understand meaning of constant density correctly.

Comment: @Hernant Rupani: I had overseen that the OP had already used $X$ for the cut point. I therefore have replaced my $X$ by $S$, which has density $2$, as stated. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I see PDF of S is 2 not X's!